# Bech32 encode/decode library for no_std to convert bytes32 into string address in runtime pallet?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, parachain, no-std, address

I want to convert bytes into string address.
I have only two options because of Junction limitation: `bytes32` or `bytes20`.

```
pub enum Junction {
   ...
   AccountId32 { network: Option<NetworkId>, id: [u8; 32] },
   ...
   AccountKey20 { network: Option<NetworkId>, key: [u8; 20] },
   ...
}
```

I want to convert `bytes32` into `bech32` string address:

```
xxxxxx1amkywxzsvshqrtw4vcsplp9v83k8w6r8auedp7
```

But there is no `no_std` library.
Is the anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependency for pallet or any code that compiled to wasm
[dependencies]
bech32 = { package = "bech32", version = "0.9.1", default-features = false, features = [
"strict",
] }